# investment formula with fixed periodical deposit and variable interest in excel

Tags: functions

Beeing far from a math guy, I've come here to ask the gurus for help :)

I have an index data imported to spreadsheet and I would like to calculate the investment return after *n* months with fixed periodical deposits starting from principal of 0. The data involves changing interest (or change of the index value) monthly.

Lets say, I would like to deposit 100$ every month for 36 months in total, starting at any moment during the history (lets say 1st of May 1901 in this case). So what will be my final yield after 36 months feeding the interest rates monthly? (1st of May 1904 in this case). Is there any useful formula that can be used in excel?

The data in spreadsheet looks like this:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkxFi.jpg)

Thanks a lot

PS. Sorry, I dont even know what is the proper tag for this question

Comment: So you invest $\$100$ in May and also in June.  During June, does the money invested in May earn at the May rate or the June rate?

Comment: I guess the may investment would earn at june rate.

Comment: Then it's simple.  Each month you increase the principal by interest on the prior balance plus $100,

Comment: Yeah, I manage to calculate it like this. I was wondering if there is a formula in excel, that would allow me to insert the data in one row and get the result for certain period of time in other cell.

Comment: I rather doubt it.